# Exchange 2003 Sending Double E-mails?

Tags: windows-server-2003, exchange-2003

We have an exchange 2003 single-machine setup that is behaving very oddly. For various users it sends the same e-mail twice (I've checked the logs and each e-mail has a unique mail identifier which confirms that the problem is not the same e-mail being received twice, but it being sent twice)

I've done a quick search and found tons of information regarding POP3/IMAP connectors etc, however these Employes are using Outlook 2003/2007 in Cached Mode.

The Symantec AntiVirus for Mail is also not causing the issue, it's correctly scanning both e-mails coming through.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't seem to be an answer here, restarted the users machine and it stopped.